# Create directory before binding via /etc/fstab

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount, fstab

I have this line in my /etc/fstab:

```
/mnt/tmp    /tmp    none    bind,nobootwait
```

On EC2 however, /mnt may be lost during restarts causing the mount to fail due to non existent /mnt/tmp. So is there a way to explicitly create this directory?

Answer (score 3):

you can make put the following lines in your /etc/rc.local file :

```
mkdir -p /mnt/tmp && mount --bind -o nobootwait /mnt/tmp /tmp
```

Comment: Does rc.local really get run before filesystems are mounted?

Comment: No you are right, but he can remove the fstab entries, no ?

Answer (score 1):

The script responsible for mounting directories from fstab is `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh`. You can add  `mkdir -p /mnt/tmp` just before the `mount -a` line. It is located in `mount_all_local()` function.

This is my `mountall.sh` script after adding the mkdir command:

```
mount_all_local() {
    mkdir -p /mnt/tmp;
    mount -a -t nonfs,nfs4,smbfs,cifs,ncp,ncpfs,coda,ocfs2,gfs,gfs2,ceph \
        -O no_netdev
}
```